# Consuming Soap Based Web service

Tags: php, soap

I need to consume a soap based web service through PHP. The URL is http://196.6.103.58:9094/PitchControlCenter/PitchControlCenterWithXML?wsdl.

I am able to do successfully both from .NET and JAVA but not able to do from PHP. The web methods described takes XML as a string in form of parameters.
Here is my Code in PHP:

```
<?php

$request= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PaymentRequest>
<Header>
<FileName>erqeqe</FileName>
<ScheduleId>AS23411323</ScheduleId>
<DebitSortCode>050</DebitSortCode>
<DebitAccountNumber>0123456789</DebitAccountNumber>
<ClientId>ERCAS_01</ClientId>
</Header>
<PaymentRecord>
<Beneficiary>salami isah</Beneficiary>
<Amount>1000.00</Amount>
<AccountNumber>0000730988</AccountNumber>
<SortCode>058</SortCode>
<Narration>this is a test</Narration>
</PaymentRecord>
<HashValue></HashValue>
</PaymentRequest>';



$url = "http://196.6.103.58:9094/PitchControlCenter/PitchControlCenterWithXML?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
$fcs = $client->__getFunctions();
//$fcs=$client->__getTypes();





$response=$client->uploadPaymentSchedule($request);

var_dump($response); // empty response



?>
```

The same works in Java where I added it as a web service and the following code works:

```
public class NibssPayPlusTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String request ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
"<PaymentRequest>\n" +
"    <Header>\n" +
"        <FileName>erqeqe</FileName>\n" +
"        <ScheduleId>AS23411323</ScheduleId>\n" +
"        <DebitSortCode>050</DebitSortCode>\n" +
"        <DebitAccountNumber>0123456789</DebitAccountNumber>\n" +
"        <ClientId>ERCAS_01</ClientId>\n" +
"    </Header>\n" +
"    <PaymentRecord>\n" +
"        <Beneficiary>salami isah</Beneficiary>\n" +
"        <Amount>1000.00</Amount>\n" +
"        <AccountNumber>0000730988</AccountNumber>\n" +
"        <SortCode>058</SortCode>\n" +
"        <Narration>this is a test</Narration>\n" +
"    </PaymentRecord>\n" +
"    <HashValue></HashValue>\n" +
"</PaymentRequest>";

        System.out.println(uploadPaymentSchedule(request));

    }

    private static String uploadPaymentSchedule(java.lang.String request) {
        com.nibss.nibsspayplus.test.PitchControlCenterWithXML_Service service = new com.nibss.nibsspayplus.test.PitchControlCenterWithXML_Service();
        com.nibss.nibsspayplus.test.PitchControlCenterWithXML port = service.getPitchControlCenterWithXMLPort();



        return port.uploadPaymentSchedule(request);
    }

}
```

I am sure missing something in PHP

Comment: please get help from frameworks. i like zend soap handler classes on this purpose